# ReOpen Window just if there is no other window open. Mac, cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, window

Hello I am working on a program which uses 2 windows.
With the main window you are able to open the second window.

If i click on the runnable file while the program is running the first window opens over the second window. Thats no wanted.
How could i exclusively open the first window if the second is not opened or minimised, otherwise i would prefer to activate the second window  without reopening the first.

I hope you could help me because i can't find anything useful in the internet. I am new to OSX programming but I am not that bad in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `NSApplicationDelegate` method [`applicationShouldHandleReopen:hasVisibleWindows:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSApplicationDelegate/applicationShouldHandleReopen:hasVisibleWindows:)

I've only used this when the app has closed all it's windows and needs to reopen one, but I believe this would work for you:

```
- (BOOL) applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)sender hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag
{
    return !flag;
}
```

That tells the `NSApp` to reopen the default way (`YES`) if there are no visible windows, and to "do nothing" (`NO`) if there are visible windows.

What seems odd, though, is that this should be the default behavior, unless your second window is an `NSPanel`.  So perhaps that is the root of your problem? Let me know if this works... happy to update with feedback.